# Representations of non-distributive lattices

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, lattice-orders

So, there are various theorems that show that you can represent a distributive lattice as some sort of lattice of sets (birkhoff, stone, priestley etc).

Are there any theorems that provide representations of any kind for any species of non-distributive lattice? (for example, representation of orthomodular lattices)

Comment: You mean like a lattice of subgroups of a group, or a lattice of partitions of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Alasdair Urquart's topological representation of bounded lattices, in general, and it includes a not-nice-at-all representation of surjective homomorphisms.

This representation specializes to Priestley's one in case the lattice is distributive.
You can find it on the paper
*A topological representation theory for lattices*
published on Algebra Universalis, 1978, pages 45-58.

If you don't have access to that, I can sketch that representation (without proofs, of course).

---

**Update.**
Actually, I already sketched that representation some time ago, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2573015/303170).